# Making fields added to attribute table appear without closing/re-opening?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I'm using ArcPy and am experiencing some troubles. I added some fields to an existing arc (coverage) but then do not appearing in attribute table. Only when i close arcgis and reopen the fields appear in attribute table.What may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

As Dan Patterson said, while the table is opened the script won't apply those changes, reaaplying it when you open the file after the closing.

Comment: can you expand your answer and/or link some documentation.